# Does "...is as dynamic a process as..." have different meaning from "...is as dynamic as a process..."?

Tags: sentence-construction, comparison, as

> **S1:** Our personal development is `as dynamic a process as` we choose to make it.

The sentence **S1** above which is from a passage in a book confused me for a while.

I could understand a sentence **S2** which is shown below.

> **S2:** Our personal development is `as dynamic as` a process when we choose to make the process dynamic.

Does `...as we choose to make it` of **S1** represent a meaning such as `when/because we choose to make it`?

Does `...as ... as we choose to make it` of **S1** compare something that I did not mention above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are very different (though in context they might come to the same meaning)

"As *x* ... as" is a phrase that can be used to qualify a noun phrase.

It is usually used with a standard of comparison, and then means "very *x*"  (eg *as good a job as I know how*, which means *the best job I am able to do*.

But sometimes it is used with a different sort of complement, as here, "(as) we choose to make it". In this case it is not expressing an extreme but variability. *as dynamic a process as we choose to make it* means that if we choose to make it dynamic, it will be dynamic, but if we don't, it won't be. In some contexts (eg an advertisement), this would probably be interpreted as the extreme, with the implication that we will choose to make it very dynamic; but in other contexts it may not have that implication.

Your second example, "as dynamic as a process when we choose to make the process dynamic", is not saying that our personal development is a process, but is comparing it to a process. In practice, this probably has the same meaning, but is not idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you. You really give me more explanation than I could expect. I learn a lot from you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Is the word "how " which appears in "as good a job as I know how" also for an idiomatic purpose?

Comment: @StatsCruncher: yes, I think so. I think it's elliptic for _as I know how to do_.

Comment: Wow! I have got more things to learn. It is like dominoes falling, right? A new question is derived from an answer which was accompanied by the earlier question, and so forth.